# ServiceStack deserialize xml to object

Tags: c#, xml, servicestack, servicestack-text

My current method for deserialization looks like this:

```
public static object Deserialize(string xml, Type toType)
{
    object result = null;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        var deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(toType);
        result = deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Can I use ServiceStack's deserialization here somehow?  Maybe I should be using something other than the FromXml method?  The important part to me is that I need to be able to pass in the `System.Type` parameter (toType) but have the result be of type `object`.

This obviously doesn't work:

```
public static object Deserialize(string xml, Type toType)
{
    object result = null;
    result = xml.FromXml<toType>();
    return result;
}
```

Neither does this:

```
public static object Deserialize(string xml, Type toType)
{
    object result = null;
    result = xml.FromXml<object>();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API to deserialize in [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) is:

```
var dto = XmlSerializer.Deserialize(xml, toType);
```

But for **XML** it's just a wrapper around .NET's Xml DataContractSerializer so it's not much of a benefit.